# Multiple custom connect configurations auto publish problem

Tags: docusignapi, docusignconnect

When I have multiply connect custom configurations but only one is Active

[image]

the 'auto publish' for events is not working.

I can publish the events only manually by selecting the Active one

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Connect configuration must be **Active** in order to work and be used to publish events.

If it's not active - it's like it's not there.

Comment: Hi Inbar, one is active and other is inactive. Please look again the first screenshot.

Comment: Yes, but you said "I can publish the events only manually by selecting the Active one" which is what I would expect. Can't use the inactive one.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding. I have only one active custom configuration which is registered to all events (envelope status and recipient status changes). When the envelope or signer status change is not triggered automatically. Is working only if I publish it manually.

Comment: Have you ever got connect to work?

Comment: Yes, it's working like a charm If I have only one custom configuration in my account. Steps to reproduce: 1.Create an active custom connect from portal 2. Disable it  3. Create an active custom configuration with docusign SDK

Comment: So, the issue is you don't know how to programmatically activate the configuration you created from the SDK?

Comment: The issue is that the connect does not publish automatically any change about the register events when I have one active and one inactive.

Comment: You can modify the code you use to activate your configuration. You can have multiple active configurations and then the events will be automatically published to all of them.